# "The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly"

Tags: c#, webclient

When i try to get html page i get this error:

```
The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly
```

I think the site I'm getting, is using some protection based on ip.

```
WebClient single_page_client = new WebClient();
single_page_client.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 1.0.3705;)");
string cat_page_single = single_page_client.DownloadString(the_url);
```

How can i do it?
What about use proxy with Webclient?

**EDIT**

If i use this code, it works. Why?

```
HttpWebRequest webrequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(current_url);
webrequest.KeepAlive = true;
webrequest.Method = "GET";
webrequest.ContentType = "text/html";
webrequest.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
//webrequest.Connection = "keep-alive";
webrequest.Host = "cat.sabresonicweb.com";
webrequest.Headers.Add("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");
webrequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:18.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/18.0";

HttpWebResponse webresponse = (HttpWebResponse)webrequest.GetResponse();

Console.Write(webresponse.StatusCode);
Stream receiveStream = webresponse.GetResponseStream();


Encoding enc = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(1252);//1252
StreamReader loResponseStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream, enc);

string current_page = loResponseStream.ReadToEnd();

loResponseStream.Close();
webresponse.Close();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first request does not utilize a header that indicates the length of the result.  It closes the connection when it finishes.

The second request utilizes the length header, reads the designated number of bytes, then closes the connection gracefully. (under the client side control instead of server driven disconnection)

-or-

The url you sent caused an error on the server.  Is there an error in the server log or event viewer?

Comment: No, i can't see any error in server log or event viewer. And as i wrote it works with HttpWebRequest. I think should be the first. thanks